# getting cpu frequency (cycles per second)- 3 different ways:

Tags: c++, linux

I have three calculation to get the curent cpu frequency: (cycles per second)

```
_initialCycles  = rdtsc(); //rdtsc function calculates the cpu cycles since init.


first:
------
unsigned int initialMillisec = (_timeVal.tv_sec)*1000+(_timeVal.tv_usec)/1000;
unsigned int cps1 = ((_initialCycles / initialMillisec) * 1000);

second:
-------
double initialMillisec2 = (_timeVal.tv_sec)*1000+(_timeVal.tv_usec)/1000.0;
unsigned int cps2 = (unsigned int)(_initialCycles / initialMillisec2 * 1000.0);

third:
------
unsigned long long initialUsec3 = 
                ((unsigned long long)(_timeVal.tv_sec))*1000000+_timeVal.tv_usec) ;
unsigned int cps3 = (unsigned int)((_initialCycles / initialUsec3)* 1000000.0);
```

the thing is, cps1 cps2 cps3 suppose to have the same value, more or less..
but they don't. I get:

```
cps1 = 2824048000
cps2 = 3824609671
cps3 = 8000000
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: I think the question title should be along the lines of "integer arithmetic in C++", because the problem is nothing to do with CPU cycles...

Comment: This should be pretty easy to solve by some printf debugging. Print out the input values to your calculation, and print out the output values of the calculation, then split out the calculation into parts and check where it starts deviating from what you expected

Comment: Weird. The first thing I'd try is to fprint every input and every intermediate value, in addition to the output. I suspect those data might be fairly telling. Otherwise, you got me!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem with integer types is in roundings. When you divide by some big number you loose significant digits. So, you should change the operation order between the multiplication and the division. First you should multiply by 1000 (or 1000000 in the case of `long long`) and only then divide.

Some examples of loosing the accuracy with the integers:

321 / 20 * 20 = 320;

321 / 75 * 75 = 300;

321 / 112 * 112 = 224

Comment: still having this problem:
    unsigned int initialMillisec = (_timeVal.tv_sec*1000) + (_timeVal.tv_usec/1000);
    unsigned int cps1 = (1000.0 * _initialCycles )/ initialMillisec ;

    double initialMillisec2 = (_timeVal.tv_sec*1000)+(_timeVal.tv_usec/1000.0);
    unsigned int cps2 = (unsigned int)((1000.0*_initialCycles) / initialMillisec2 );

    unsigned long long initialUsec3 = ((unsigned long long)(_timeVal.tv_sec))*1000000+(_timeVal.tv_usec) ;
    unsigned int cps3 = (unsigned int)(_initialCycles * 1000000.0 / initialUsec3);

   cps1 = 2824174819
   cps2 = 3619552765
   cps3 = 8260420

Comment: Another problem you have is the overflow. For example, in the first case when you perform `(_timeVal.tv_sec)*1000` the resulting value overflows the size of int

Answer (score 2):

There are many other threads and processes running at the same time and the OS scheduler might inter fear with this method of measuring the frequency.

Try using the "cpufreq" utility to accurately get the current clock speed.

Comment: You can either do :

'sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq'

Or 

'cat /proc/cpuinfo'

and then possibly do some string manipulation to get just the number you need.

Comment: Thanks Feni.I didn't want to use this file.. I actually wanted to calculate the cycles per seconds (since the boot)

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence and implicit conversions.

Of course you need to make sure the operators get evaluated in the order you desire. My best advice: add parens if you would have to think twice to know the order without parens.

Then: you need to convert the ints to floats early, or you'll end up with integer division and ditto rounding errors.

```
unsigned int initialMillisec = _timeVal.tv_sec*1000 + _timeVal.tv_usec/1000;
unsigned int cps1 = (1.0 * _initialCycles / initialMillisec) * 1000.0;
```

would be my suggestion